# OpenGL 3+ with Python 3

Tags: python, opengl

I want to write a visualization for some complex scientific data in Python. I have done a similar thing a few years ago in Objective-C/Cocoa/OpenGL. The visualization will contain some fancy shader programs, so at least OpenGL 3.0 is required. Also, I need to draw a window and do some mouse/keyboard handling. Some GUI widgets would be nice, but not required. Python 3 support is highly desirable.

I looked into:

- PyOpenGL, which has no window/mouse/keyboard handling.
- PyGlet, which only supports Python 2.7.
- PyQt, which only supports OpenGL 2.0.
- PySide, which is pretty much dead, and stuck in Qt 4.7.
- wxPython, which only supports Python 2.7.
- PyGame, which is pretty much dead.

Do you know any library that can do modern OpenGL and some windowing in Python 3?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is PyOpenGL plus PyQt. Python plus either Pyglet or wxPython are possible alternatives.

PyOpenGL (the Mike Fletcher version, right?) is the best Python OpenGL API I know of. It has support for OpenGL 3 and 4 and is just very nice and Pythonic.

PyQt itself only supports OpenGL 2, but PyOpenGL will run inside a PyQt context. Since PyQt does have a Python 3 version, this combination should meet your needs.

For the GUI stuff I prefer wxPython, but as you note that hasn't been updated for Python 3 yet. You could take a look at the wxPython Phoenix project, but that's very much a work in progress.

Pyglet is also quite nice but has less GUI functionality that wxPython or PyQt. Think of it as the equivalent of GLUT. The Python 3 version is currently in alpha, but given that it's not a complete rewrite I'd expect it to be stable very soon.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I actually tried that using a QGLWidget, but the context I got there only supported OpenGL 2.1. How do I create my own OpenGL context in PyQt?

Comment: PyQt only supports OpenGL 2; but PyOpenGL has bindings for 3 and 4. Run PyOpenGL inside PyQt and you should be able to use later version stuff, unless A) your graphics card can't actually do OpenGL 3+, or B) the PyQt config is deliberately lowering the version requested

Comment: When I use PyOpenGL within PyQt, it reports that it only supports OpenGL 2.1 (via `glGetString(gl.GL_VERSION)`).

Comment: If your system is GL 3 or better according to glxinfo/OpenGL Extension  Viewer/etc, then PyQt must be explicitly requesting only version 2. You'll have to hack the Qt code or switch to Pyglet/wxWindows